# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected character "EOF"

Tags: angular, angular2-template

i am calling a function from HTML, the function is this

```
formvalidation(rownumber: number, controlname?: string) {   
    return true;
  }
```

and the HTML is this

```
 <input [ngClass]="{'error':formvalidation('i','"'fromDate'"') }" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='fromDate' />
```

here, fromDate is a static value which i pass through the function, the code works fine if i pass it like this

```
formvalidation('i')
```

only the first parameter withhout the **fromDate** but when i pass with **fromDate** i get an error as mentioned above

Comment: `'"'fromDate'"'`: that's not valid. What are you trying to do here? If you're trying to pass the string 'fromDate', then just use `'fromDate'`. If you're tryig to pass the value of the fromDate property of your component, then use `fromDate`.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are not used properly. Change the code to

`<input [ngClass]="{'error':formvalidation('i','fromDate') }" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='fromDate' />`